# Is it possible to show/hide links on the left action menu based on Group?

Tags: list

I want to hide links to Lists based on the Group from the user.

Example:

- Trainer should see the links to list **"A"** and **"B"**.
- Student should only see the link to List **"A"**.

Is this possible using standard SharePoint permissions ? Or should I use *jQuery + SPServices* to remove a link if the user is not in the correct Group?

(In asp.net this can be done using a sitemap.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create Trainer and Student groups and add users to these groups accordingly.
2. Stop inheriting permissions from parent for list A and list B.
3. Configure permissions for each list, main point being that Students don't have access to list B.

No need to do any custom coding or jQuery whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK standard list links should be hidden if user have no access rights to the list

Answer (score 1):

You have the ability to audience links and other content if you are using MOSS and enable the publishing infrastructure. This way you can use either a SharePoint group, a distribution group, or you can define global audiences in the SSP and use those as well to audience your links. This applies to both links on the left (local) and across the top (global) for MOSS.